# Center form items in div outside of form

Tags: html, css, forms

I have complex form section that actually contains two forms side by side. The main form is on the right and I need this form's submit buttons to be centered in the form conatiner. Here's a fiddle of a simplified version of what I'm dealing with:

https://jsfiddle.net/as2e4d0d/5/

The html for the fiddle:

```
<div class="form post-form">
  <div class="post-form__left">
    <form class="form__form" method="POST" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8">
      <textarea type="text" class="form__input post-form__question-input" autocomplete="off" name="question" placeholder="Ask a new question"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Ask" class="button button--green post-form__question-button">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="post-form__right">
    <form class="post-form__form" method="POST" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8">
      <div class="form__section post-form__textarea-container">
        <textarea class="form__input post-form__textarea" type="text" name="body" placeholder="Write your entry"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="post-form__bottom">
        <div class="form__section form__button-row post-form__buttons">
          <input class="form__button button button--ghost" type="submit" name="type" value="Save Draft">
          <input class="form__button button button--ghost" type="submit" name="type" value="Publish">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css for the fiddle:

```
.post-form {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
 }

.post-form__left {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}
.post-form__right {
  flex: 3 0 66.67%;
}

.post-form__question-button {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.post-form__left textarea {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.post-form__right textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.post-form__bottom {
  position: absolute;
}
```

I need the "post-form__bottom" div, with the "Save Draft" and "Publish" buttons, to be centered in the top level "post-form". In the fiddle, the buttons need to be centered in the red box. Ive tried setting position absolute on "post-form__bottom", but that did nothing. I tried messing around with negative margins, but that got really messy and I could never get it right. Any help would be appreciated.

**Solution**
Set width to 100%. Rookie mistake!
https://jsfiddle.net/as2e4d0d/6/

Comment: Which position for `post-form__bottom`? Sorry, I don't understand about your question :)

Comment: He wants the two buttons to be placed in the middle, relative to the second textarea

Comment: I want post-form__bottom to be centered in the top level div, with class "form post-form". So relative to the parent, outside the form.

Comment: Just updated the fiddle. I need them centered in the red box.

Comment: try see my demo. @revolt_101

Comment: Thanks Fiido93, but I need them centered relative to the main div (red box in my updated fiddle).

Comment: @revolt_101 can u try draw your achieve layout?

Comment: Got it. I wasn't setting width to 100%.   
Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/as2e4d0d/6/

Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: You can use my solution with `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set width to 100%, left to 0.

https://jsfiddle.net/as2e4d0d/6/

```
.post-form {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
 }

.post-form__left {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}
.post-form__right {
  flex: 3 0 66.67%;
}

.post-form__question-button {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.post-form__left textarea {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.post-form__right textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.post-form__bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: why do you think this is the effective way?

Comment: Because the buttons are centered in the RED box, just like I wanted. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: what is the different between red box or black box? what i see is the red box is at outside. 
https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/as2e4d0d/4/

Comment: In your fiddle the buttons are centered relative to the form, not the outer box.      
In this fiddle, they are centered relative to the outer, red box:
https://jsfiddle.net/as2e4d0d/12/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to centering your button form.

You shouldn't use

```
.post-form__bottom {
   position:absolute;
}
```

Change it to this it will center your button form

```
.post-form__bottom {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/as2e4d0d/4/)

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in the first post. I updated the fiddle. I need them centered in the red box.  
https://jsfiddle.net/as2e4d0d/5/

Comment: you just want the button on right hand side is to be center right?

Answer (score 0):

```
.post-form__buttons {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Make sure parent of `.post-form__buttons` (`.post-form`) has `position: relative`

Answer (score 0):

```
.post-form__bottom {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/as2e4d0d/11/